# How to Integrate TortoiseSVN with Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I have always used **TortoiseSVN** + Notepad++ to develop websites and applications in a shared repository. But I want to use **Eclipse IDE** instead of Notepad++. 
I did a checkout to my SVN repository with TortoiseSVN and now I want to import the SVN project (a *Liferay project*) into Eclipse and commit files to SVN repository directly from Eclipse IDE.
How can i accomplish this?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to install an SVN Plugin. I would recommend Subversive you can find it in the Eclipse Marketplace (`Help` -> `Eclipse Marketplace...`).

After this you have to install an SVN Connector. I would recomment SVNKit. Then you can open the Eclipse perspective `SVN Repository Exploring` and configure your SVN repository.

Now you can make all SVN operations directly from Eclipse and there is no need to use TortoiseSVN anymore.

Comment: SVNKit was the fix for no javaHL error! The error was telling me Window>Preferences>Team>SVN>SVN Connector. What I was missing was that SVN Connector is a **_tab_** on the SVN menu page. Once there, there was a button "Get Connectors" which included SVN Kit, as well as javaHL 1.8 and 1.9. I chose 1.9 and things started working a whole lot better.

Answer (score 10):

The easiest is to use a SVN plugin for eclipse such as Subclipse - http://subclipse.tigris.org/. Once installed you would not have any dependency to TortoiseSVN.

Also note that if you wish to use both Subclipse and TortoiseSVN on the same files on your file system, your working copy format version supported by the respective clients must be the same.

Comment: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x 
the url you can directly access to install subclipse.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin which allows simple usage of Tortoise SVN (and also Beyond Compare) in Eclipse:
https://github.com/ContextQuickie/ContextQuickie

Answer (score 0):

The 2 Phase Installation instructions are provided in the Eclipse site which I followed to install Tortoise SVN in my Eclipse Luna.
I followed the Phase I - Option 1 and Phase 2, which worked well for me.

http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php