# How to use TortoiseSVN and Subversive Eclipse plugin with same files in filesystem?

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subversive

I followed this [asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759562/how-to-integrate-tortoisesvn-with-eclipse-ide) in order to integrate both, TortoiseSVN and Subversive Eclipse plugin. So i´ve tried this two paths.

1. Check out my SVN Project with Tortoise SVN
2. Import with Eclipse IDE `File -> Import -> Existing Porjects into Workspace`.
3. Open Eclipse perspective SVN Repository Exploring and added my `SVN repository`.

But I don´t know how to have the subversive options when I right click on my Java Project in Project Explorer. They aren´t binded.

The other path.

1. Import with Eclipse IDE `File -> Import -> SVN -> Project from SVN`

This is O.K and I can make commit and update to my project but the project folder it´s not administrable with Tortoise SVN.

I missed some step. Please help!

Comment: Usually it doesn't matter which SVN client you use. If one SVN client doesn't work with a specific repository this may indicate that the version is too old or to new. New versions sometimes change the local data structure for SVN metadata: old version can not work on new version data and new version do not work on old data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import projects that are under control of a source control system using "File -> Import -> Existing Porjects into Workspace", you can hookup Eclipse source control integration by right-clicking on the project and using the "Team -> Share" menu. Find SVN under there and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

The subversive Eclipse plugin is the Eclipse integration of a SVN client.

You thus don't need to checkout your project with tortoise SVN.

Instead, once you have installed subversive and an SVN connector, just create a new repository location in your svn repository view and checkout your project from there.

once the project is checked using subversive (and not tortoise) you will have all the subversive options.

Another way to do it, is to right click on the project / TEAM  / connect project.

Comment: Yes, I could view the subversive options. I was only asking if I could have both clients working with the same working and updated copy.

Comment: okay i misunderstood the question. I think that if you setup tortoiseSVN after subversive, there should'nt be any problem. You just need to pay attention that both tortoise and subversive use the same subversion version. i guess that a different version might lead to some conflicts in the metafiles