# CF Builder and Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, coldfusion, tortoisesvn

Can I configure Tortoise SVN with CF Builder? I have been looking but can't find much online. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Instead of searching for Tortoise SVN with CF Builder, try Tortoise SVN with Eclipse instead. The instructions should be the same. Then you will find things like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18759844/1636917

Answer (score 0):

CFBuilder is Eclipse based. As such you need to use an Eclipse plugin for SVN. The one I recommend is Subversive.  I wrote a blog post a while back detailing how to install and configure the plugin.  https://www.trunkful.com/index.cfm/2011/7/11/ColdFusion-Builder-2-and-the-Subversive-Plugin

Cheers.